# Junit : which is the best and easy frame work for testing JSP and Servlet

Tags: junit

> which will the best and easy frame work for testing JSP and Servlet. I
>   am bit confuse among HttpUnit and cactus Please help.......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without much background it's hard to know your requirements. What are you trying to do? Is this old school Java or some offshoot (Groovy et al.)?

At its most basic you can test your servlet using Junit and EasyMock (mocking the httpservletrequest/response and validating interactions).

As for front-end testing, I'd investigate webdriver. That'll allow you to interact with the page using HTMLUnit, Firefox, Chrome, etc. There's a good Groovy-based abstraction of webdriver in the form of Geb (bookofgeb) that I'd also suggest for building maintainable tests.

I'd avoid unit testing (in the pure form) "views". You shouldn't have any form of complex code in your view so the need for unit testing should be negated. (And unit testing views are a PITA for maintainability.)

Review your requirements and tell us your objectives.

Comment: I had to test a server side servlet which parse the form data and perform the required business logic